# Class 'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, sql, laravel, upgrade, lamp

I'm in the process of upgrading my Laravel from 5.2 to 5.3 and have gone through the documentation on https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade, but I still get this message when I run my application:

> FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class
>   'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider' not found

I already added Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider to the providers and Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification to the alias in config/app.php.  I also tried:

> composer dump-autoload
>   composer update --no-scripts

to prevent artisan from executing before it was included, but to no avail.

Comment: What is your composer.json `autoload` configuration? I suggest trying `composer dump-autoload -o`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Need to run `composer install` after upgrading Laravel.